# Django getting value from a Jquery Post

Tags: jquery, python, django

Task: it is the implementation of checking on the fly at run time if a word has been taken

I have used jquery in the past and never had problems with PHP but I m new to Django:

This code is imported in a page called home.py and it will want to send the value picked from a textfield to a receiving page called checkkeyword.py. But before getting to that I wanted to see if the receiving page actually responded and the baffling thing is that what I get is the whole content of what  is written in checkkeyword.py.

That is, I enter a character in the text field, and yes, I get a reply right next to it, but the reply is the full content of whatever is written in checkkeyword.py. **Why**?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#keyword').keyup(function() {
        var keyword = $(this).val();
        $('#keyword_status').text('searching ...');
        if(keyword!= ''){
            $.post(
               '/static/js/checkkeyword.py',
               {param: keyword},
               function (data){
                   $('#keyword_status').text(data);
            });
         }
     });


});
```

If `checkkeyword.py` contains "hello", it will return `hello`. If it contains `print("hello")`, it will return `print("hello")` etc

For testing purposes, I placed, as you can see, the `checkkeyword.py` inside the same directory where the jQuery file is.

I have seen some posts about it, like writing something like this>

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
   print(request)
```

but, as expected, it returns me all of those 4 lines of code, not the value of request.

Please: no bullying comments about my incompetence or downvotes. I just got started.

Thank you.

Comment: are you running it on a server?? localhost or something?

Comment: on a web server, I am using c9.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to unlearn what you have learned :-) The problem is that you're assuming that simply dropping a Python file into the static folder will automatically mean that the Python code inside is executed (which isn't the case -- you are simply getting the **contents** back as if it was an image, a text file or whatever else may reside in the static folder)

You have to

1. add the view code in a `views.py` file, maybe inside the same folder as your `settings.py` file.
2. register the view in your `urls.py` file, maybe as follows.

Code sample:

```
from .views import my_view

urlpatterns = [
    # The following line may already be there:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # This is the new line you're adding:
    url(r'^my-view/$', my_view),
]
```

Then, try POSTing to `/my-view/` and see whether you get any results.

Also, I'll **very strongly** suggest you to work through the tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ first. It will hopefully help you understand the relationship between URLs, views, and how the request-response processing works with Django.

Good luck!

Regarding CSRF: Disabling the CSRF protection at first may work for you, but please study https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/ and re-enable CSRF when installing the application on a public-facing server.